# Sonata Admin: non-existent service "security.authorization_checker"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to set up a simple CMS using Sonata Admin Bundle. I use composer to add `sonata-project/admin-bundle` and `sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle` to an empty git repository, then follow the rest of the directions on https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html

Now I visit `http://localhost/admin/dashboard`, which the instructions say should give me a blank dashboard. Instead, I get a ServiceNotFoundException, stating:

> The service "sonata.admin.menu.group_provider" has a dependency on a
> non-existent service "security.authorization_checker".

Is there a bundle or configuration that I need to install/add in order to fix this?

===

When I run `bin/console debug:container security.authorization_checker` I get the following output:

> In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 86:
>
> The service "sonata.admin.menu.group_provider" has a dependency on a
> non-existent service "secur   ity.authorization_checker".

===

Here is config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml:

```
sonata_block:
  blocks:
    # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
      contexts: [admin]
```

... and here is config/services.yaml:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

... and here is my bundles.php:

```
return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\Doctrine\Bridge\Symfony\SonataDoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\Form\Bridge\Symfony\SonataFormBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\Twig\Bridge\Symfony\SonataTwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Comment: could you please post your config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml and config/services.yaml here

Comment: Hi @Adi -- thanks for your comment. I just added them.

Comment: Have you enabled the Security bundle, in `bundles.php`?

Comment: Good question, @yivi. I just checked `bundles.php`, and it looks like the security bundle is already present there. (I've added bundles.php content to the body of the question.)

Comment: and if you run `bin/console debug:container security.authorization_checker` you get "no services found"?

Comment: I get the same error when I run that command. (I've added that to the question as well now.)

Comment: Have you cleared cache? `rm -rf var/cache/*`?

Comment: Yes. Clearing that cache did not fix the problem.

Comment: What version of Symfony / Sonata are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Mcsky. This is Sonata 3.99 running atop Symfony 4.4.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install symfony security. And maybe flex, if you don't already have it.

```
composer require symfony/flex
composer require security
```

That will automatically install and configure the bundle for you.